# Jquery toggleClass issue - same code works with addClass - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I'm trying to toggle a class of "on" with jquery, but doesn't seem to be working.  addClass does work, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

this works:

```
$(".request-trial").click(function () {
  $("#request-trial").addClass("on");
});
```

but this does not:

```
$(".request-trial").click(function () {
  $("#request-trial").toggleClass("on");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated..!

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: One "request-trial" is a class, (that you click on) the other an id, that you toggle the "on" class to and the id is unique on the page. Correct?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, though i'm guessing you didn't mean `#request-trial` inside the click event and instead need either `$(this)` or `$(".request-trial")`

```
<div id="request-trial" class="request-trial"></div>
```

---

```
$(".request-trial").click(function () { 
    $("#request-trial").toggleClass("on");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hXxjY/

Comment: No it's a separate button on another part of the page with that class that is supposed to trigger the class toggle on the #request-trial div. Hmm....

Comment: In that case your code should work as-is, it does for me. Copy the code and surrounding code into notepad++ and look for special/weird characters.

Comment: Or possibly a typo in the ID or js id selector, or maybe even duplicate id's, none of which we can find without relevant html.

Comment: Got it - was a wonky character that wasn't displaying in my editor stuck in the middle - fixed and working. thanks for the suggestion to check in another editor!